# Is Marketing Cloud Custom activity save() method supported by other programming language, like Java, pathon, other than Node.js?

Tags: marketing-cloud, node.js

Since SFMC SMS/MMS service isn't available in some countries other than the U.S, we have to build our own custom activity within marketing cloud for SMS/MMS sending by calling out 3rd party SMS/MMS sending service. 
As we learned, save() function is used for saving custom app configurations by sending data from custom app to salesforce marketing cloud. However, this save() function can only be invoking by using Node.js programming method. Regarding this fact, we have two questions need clarification from your side:
1. Is this save() method supported by other web programming language, like Java, pathon?
2. If other programming languages are not supported, can we execute Node.js SDK from the front-end, instead of executing it from the background?

Answer (score 2):

Custom Activities can be written in any language or framework. They are certainly not limited to Node.js. There are two options for retrieving save data.

### Save Endpoint

Journey Builder will make a request with the Activity parameters to the `save` URL defined in the `configurationArguments` object in your config.json file

### Postmonger Event

Journey Builder uses [Postmonger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/using-postmonger.htm) for cross-domain messaging between Journey Builder and the Custom Activity interface (displayed in an iframe on the Journey Canvas). this a lightweight Javascript utility (not Node.js) which should be able to be used with most application frameworks.

When a Custom Activity is added to the Journey Canvas, default values for `arguments`, `configurationArguments` and `metaData` are loaded from the Activity’s config.json file. Any subsequent loading of a Custom Activity’s configuration interface will load the data from the Activity’s model. As the data is sent to the Custom Activity’s configuration interface each time it is loaded, the entire object should be sent as a payload when the Custom Activity is saved.

The `updateActivity` event is called when the Custom Activity iframe needs to close and data from the Custom Activity interface needs to be saved. This event expects an Activity definition payload to be passed.

The `toJbPayload` parameter should be set to the payload received on `initActivity` and modified based on user inputs in the Custom Activity interface.

The parameter `toJbPayload.metaData.isConfigured` must be set to `true` for Journey Builder to recognize that the activity is fully configured (when the Journey is published).

```js
var toJbPayload = {};
toJbPayload.metaData.isConfigured = true;
connection.trigger('updateActivity', toJbPayload);
```

### SMS Alternative in Marketing Cloud

**Before you run off and build your own SMS integration**, I would encourage you to contact [Pierry](https://pierryinc.com/) as they have built a HubExchange app for Marketing Cloud (with an interface very similar to MobileConnect). In APAC, Salesforce recommends Pierry's solution for countries where MobileConnect is not supported.

Comment: Thank you, Eliot! Your comments help a lot! We will take a deep look into this based on your suggestion.